# KineticJS line follows mouse position

Tags: kineticjs

how do I draw a line beginning from fixed coordinates to the actual mouse position?

```
show_connect_line = new Kinetic.Line({
    points : [parseInt(show_connect_line_beginx), parseInt(show_connect_line_beginy),parseInt(stage.getMousePosition().x),parseInt(stage.getMouePosition().y)],
    name : 'line',
    stroke : '#555',
    strokeWidth : 2,
    lineCap : 'butt',
    id : 'show_connect_line'
});
```

This doesn't work because of "getMousePosition()"

THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
stage.getMouePosition().y s/b stage.getMousePosition().y
```

BTW, The current version of KineticJS uses stage.getPointerPosition().  That may be a problem also.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/fF8AP/